# Displaying Date only MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this `model`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
namespace PrototypeHelp.Models
{

    public class DocumentModel
    {   
        public int documentID { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public int authorID { get; set; }
        public String AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int categoryID { get; set; }
        public String Category { get; set; }
        public int topicID { get; set; }
        public String Topic { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String DocumentBody { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to display only the date using `jquery` but I cant get rid of the in "DateCreated".

Can anyone help me? I'm displaying it by using `jquery`

Comment: Are you sending this object via ajax to the client?

Comment: sorry my bad wrong post im displaying that using @MODEL in the view and im using c# codes not jquery


like this @HTML.Encode(document.DateCreated)

Comment: do i have to add a code to display just the date?

Answer (score 9):

use this in your model definition for date

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: Hi i think it didnt resolve my problem this is what i did

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

To display the date you can either decorate the property with a [DisplayFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute.  This value is the format in which you want to display the date.

for example

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

or alternatively, in the view you can specify the format in the `ToString()` function.

```
@Model.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```